# How to make the opencv-contrib module work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, sift, opencv-contrib

I followed this guide to install opencv (version 3.4.4) and the contrib modules because I want to work with the SIFT algorithm.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/
When I noticed, it was not working as expected after the installation, I deleted the build folder and tried again, but this did not work as well.
I imported like this:

```
import cv2 as cv
```

I tried to use SIFT (in python 3.6) in the following ways:

```
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
sift = cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
sift = cv.SIFT()
sift = cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT()
```

As this usually results in errors like this: Attribute Error: module cv2 has no attribute 'SIFT_create' (same thing happens for the other 3 options), I figure that I am either using it in an incorrect way or the installation process itself did not work properly.

After this, I found the pip install opencv-contrib-python and used it. With no results at all.

I would really appreciate some hints on how I can make opencv with contrib modules work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to say `cv2.xfeatures2d_SIFT` or similar. the modules of OpenCV don't necessarily map to python submodules.

Since the patent on SIFT expired in 2019, OpenCV moved it back into `features2d` (main repo) from `xfeatures2d` (opencv_contrib repo). Please use the most recent 3.4.x release, or 4.x.